# Meteor - return all documents from collection 1 and then query collection 2 as looping through collection 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor, hidden

I am very new to Meteor (and web programming) and setup two collections, one called Posts and the other Authors (I do realize I could put all this information in one collection but I want to try it this way). I am trying to display all posts so I am doing eachPost in the HTML code which will loop through all my Posts. As I am looping through my Posts, I am trying to save the post id in a Hidden input so I can use that id for each post to query the Authors collection and display the Author name. I added a console.log and it writes undefined every time for my postId - any idea why this is doing this or a better way to solve this problem (without embedding author information in Posts)?

html:

```
<template name="dashboard">
  {{#each eachPost}}
    <input type="hidden" id="postId" value="{{_id}}">
    <p>{{authorName}}</p>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

js:

```
Template.dashboard.helpers({
 eachPost: function()
 {
   return Posts.find({});
 },

 authorName: function()
 {
   var postId = $('#postId').val();
   console.log(postId);
   return Authors.findOne({_id: postId});
 }
});
```

Thanks in advance, I really appreciate any and all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no need to store it in a hidden element

you can access it by using `this._id` in `authorname` helper

You can do like below

```
<template name="dashboard">
  {{#each eachPost}}
    <p>{{authorName}}</p>
  {{/each}}
</template>

Template.dashboard.helpers({
 eachPost: function()
 {
   return Posts.find({});
 },

 authorName: function()
 {

   console.log(this._id);
   return Authors.findOne({_id: this._id});
 }
});
```

Try this,it may work for you